# Increment variable after each 3 hours in PHP

Tags: php, wordpress, loops, time

I need some idea from you guys. I'm thinking about creating a counter which will start from 17 and after each 3 hours it's gonna increase by 1. Then After each weeks Tuesday 12:00am the counter is again gonna reset to 17 and follow the same approach.

I'm actually gonna create a wordpress shortcode with it, but I know how to do that so, doesn't looking help for that.

The help I'm looking for actually is how I'm gonna achieve on PHP. Because I thought it cannot be done normally with `for` loop. So, what I'm asking for is actually some tips and idea from you geeks that how should I proceed with the code and may be what different functions I may use to get this result.

Any idea guys?

Comment: Are you aware of cron jobs ?

Comment: You can deduct time when counter start from actual time.And use the difference to calculate the value.

Comment: @Akshay - yes man I am, but as I said I'm gonna create a shortcode inside the `function.php` of wordpress, it's doesn't seems a good idea to run the function.php five via cron jobs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For this case I wouldn't recommend a cron job. You can calculate the difference in time and use that to calculate the amount of hours that have passed.

```
$varToIncrement = 17;

$now         = new DateTime('now');
$thisTuesday = new DateTime('this Tuesday 12:00');

# If this Tuesday 12:00 is in the past, use that
# Else use last Tuesday (last week)
if ($now > $thisTuesday) {
    $lastTuesday = $thisTuesday;
} else {
    $lastTuesday = new DateTime('last Tuesday 12:00');
}

# Calculate how many hours between the 2 dates
$hours = getHoursBetween($lastTuesday, $now);

# Increment our variable with the amount of hours divided by 3
# Also use floor() to round down
$varToIncrement += floor($hours / 3);

# Et voila!
echo $varToIncrement;

function getHoursBetween($date1, $date2)
{
    # Create a DateInterval (difference between dates)
    $diff = $date2->diff($date1);

    # Return difference in hours
    return $diff->h + ($diff->days * 24);
}
```

Comment: This is freaking awesome man. But I have 2 questions in your code - 1. the `12:00` you mentioned when calling `DateTime` inbuilt php class does that in 12 hour format or 24 hours format? Because it its 24 hrs format then `24:00` makes more sense.
2. the function you have created `getHoursBetween` is expecting two date variables to pass, but in my case I have no variables to pass. It will not stop, after certain date. It's just keep doing this over and over.

Comment: Oh! OK. I got it. I was reading the code wrongly. Thanks, man I'm gonna test it now and if it works I'm definitely gonna mark it as BEST ANSWER. So, give me a few hours to test it.

Comment: Just let me know about the Timing thing, because if it's 24 hours based then I'm going with `24:00`

Comment: I read over the AM part of your question, my answer uses the 24h system. You could just leave the 12:00 part out, it should default to 00:00 (midnight).

Comment: Great also in the `$varToIncrement += floor($hours / 3);` does it incrementing by 1?

Comment: It adds 1 for every 3 hours difference. For example 18 hours have passed: `floor(18 /  3) = 6`, so it will increment by 6.